# PrimeFaces FileUpload button clickable outside of buttons bounds

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm working with the PrimeFaces file upload button and it works as intended but my cursor is able to click it while not in the bounds of the button. This is possible specifically if the cursor is both

- below the upper bound of the button
- to the left of the right bound of the button.

There does appear to be some lower bound to this clickable area outside of the button but there is not a clear marker like there is for the upper and right bounds.

I am currently using PrimeFaces 6.0, and my WebLogic server is version 12.1.2.0. There are also no errors being printed to the console.

Are there errors in my xhtml that is causing it or is it related to an issue with PrimeFaces? Would it be possible to change the clickable area with CSS without changing the actual button size?

**XHTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/main.xhtml">
<h:head></h:head>
<ui:define name="pagebody">

    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="script.js" />

    <h:body>

        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
            onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

        <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
            closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </p:dialog>


        <h:form id="uploadform" prependId="false"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
            onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">

            <p:focus />

            <p:outputPanel id="container">
                <center>
                    <h2>File Upload</h2>
                </center>
                <br />
                <center>
                    <font color="red"> <b><p:messages id="messages"
                                styleClass="error" /></b>
                    </font>
                </center>
                <center>
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
                        update="submitButton" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|xlsx)$/" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitButton" actionListener="#{uploadBean.submitFile}" 
                        styleClass="ui-priority-primary" update="submitButton" disabled="#{! (uploadBean.enableSubmit)}"/>

                </center>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Did you check WHAT the clickable area is? Browser developer tools help a lot. Cannot reproduce in https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml. Please make a [mcve] (no template, dialog, custom js etc) since there is a very big chance it is a problem created by custom css or a theme... And tried the latest PF?

Comment: @Kukeltje When I tried with the latest version it was still there but the size was greatly reduced. I also took your advice in trying to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example and that got rid of the issue so I am going to add pieces back until I can locate what caused it to occur. I'll report back when possible. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Thanks for following the advice. Creating an [mcve] and using (at least trying) the latest versions and running in development mode always helps a lot narrowing down the problem and creating a better question (if not already solving it like here)

Comment: @Kukeltje You were correct in that it was a css issue. The style sheet I borrowed only contains fileupload css for .fileupload-content and .fileupload-buttonbar. I tried removing both of those from the style sheet but the issue is there with or without them. I am going have to read the rest of the file to figure it out, but thank you for helping me clarify where my issue was.